# The usage of "I see not"

Tags: phrase-usage

I've read a lot of novels written in English, and one thing I've come across many times is the phrase "I see not..." (e.g *I see not how this plan is going to work*). I am very curious as to whether "I see not" is a more "formal" or "literary" form of "I don't see" or not and would very much like to know more about how I can correctly use it.

Please excuse any grammatical mistakes I might have made, English is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR I'd consider it archaic rather than formal or literary.

Other than "I am not", "I have not", "I can not", and "I do not" (and possibly a few other exceptions), it's pretty rare to have the construction "I *verb* not" in modern English.

In fact, in the case of "have not" and "can not", it's usually the case that the next word is a verb, so the **main** verb isn't followed by *not* in those cases either.